# Lerna does not support dependencies at the top level?

Tags: npm, lerna

I am in the process of switching my monorepo (back) from yarn (with workspaces) to lerna/npm, because yarn is too slow and unstable. However, I made an surprising discovery. With the following trivial `package.json`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": { "lerna": "^2.11.0" },
  "dependencies":    { "typescript": "^2.9.1" }
}
```

and an empty `lerna.json` (in other words, no packages at all), then when I run

```
$ lerna bootstrap
```

it does not install anything at all in any top-level `node_modules` directory. And if for some reason I have a `node_modules` directory with no `.bin` subdirectory, then `lerna bootstrap` fails to create or populate the `.bin` subdirectory.

Is lerna not designed to actually specify top-level packages which are to be installed (along with their binaries in `.bin`)? I do notice that if I try `lerna add` on a lerna monorepo with no packages, it complains that "lerna WARN No packages found in scope where tslint can be added."

I could not find anything related to this in the documentation. With yarn/workspaces, I was using the ability to install global (top-level) versions of things like TypeScript for use in my build scripts while maintaining control over the version installed.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem right now, any update on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Lerna docs:

> You can add the root as a managed location (in the packages array of `lerna.json`) - if that's something you need. This would cause lerna to link root's dependencies to your packages' directories, run `postinstall` script along with the others, etc.